# C# lock based on class property

Tags: c#, locking

I've seen many examples of the `lock` usage, and it's usually something like this:

```
private static readonly object obj = new object();

lock (obj)
{
    // code here
}
```

Is it possible to lock based on a property of a class? I didn't want to lock globally for any calls to the method with the `lock` statement, I'd like to lock only if the object passed as argument had the same property value as another object which was being processed prior to that.

Is that possible? Does that make sense at all?

This is what I had in mind:

```
public class GmailController : Controller
{

    private static readonly ConcurrentQueue<PushRequest> queue = new ConcurrentQueue<PushRequest>();

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult ProcessPushNotification(PushRequest push)
    {
        var existingPush = queue.FirstOrDefault(q => q.Matches(push));
        if (existingPush == null)
        {
            queue.Enqueue(push);
            existingPush = push;
        }
        try
        {
            // lock if there is an existing push in the
            // queue that matches the requested one
            lock (existingPush)
            {
                // process the push notification
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            queue.TryDequeue(out existingPush);
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Background**: I have an API where I receive push notifications from Gmail's API when our users send/receive emails. However, if someone sends a message to two users at the same time, I get two push notifications. My first idea was querying the database before inserting (based on subject, sender, etc). In some rare cases, the query of the second call is made before the `SaveChanges` of the previous call, so I end up having duplicates.

I know that if I ever wanted to scale out, `lock` would become useless. I also know I could just create a job to check recent entries and eliminate duplicates, but I was trying something different. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: It's typically a bad idea to ever lock on an object that could ever be locked on outside of whatever class you're in.  Ensuring that the object you're locking on is only ever accessible in the current class means you only need to look at that one class to understand how that object can be locked on, which makes ensuring there aren't deadlocks or inappropriate lock contention **much** easier.  If you're inclined to have a object locked on from multiple classes, it's usually worth redesigning your code such that you no longer need that, even if that takes a bit of work.

Comment: I guess I'll just allow duplicates, and try a different approach (e.g make a distinct when displaying in the frontend app). I feel like using `lock` seems a bit hacky at this point. I should probably try something simpler.

Comment: Sounds like a problem to solve at the database end rather than on the application side of things.  Have a constraint or trigger that won't allow the record to be inserted that shouldn't be, and handle the resulting error in the application code.  Because DBs are inherently multi-application, it should be what does the synchronization for something like this.

Comment: I edited the question with the code I had in mind. Although I'm not sure that does make sense.

Comment: My answer explains why you want to be very careful about doing this in general. But leaving aside the merits of doing it at all: your specific code is very broken! This thing is a *mass* of race conditions.

Comment: Suppose for example two push requests that are not reference equal but match -- call them "frob 1" and "frob 2" -- come in on two different threads, 1 and 2 respectively. Now we are racing. The queue is empty.  existingPush on thread1 is null. We switch threads. existingPush on thread 2 is null.  Switch back to thread 1. We enqueue frob1 and existingPush is now frob1. Switch back to thread 2.  We enqueue frob2 and existingPush is now frob2.  We now have two threads with two different lock objects, and your desired lock property is not maintained.

Comment: Or, again, frob1 comes in on thread 1, goes in the queue, we take the lock, we leave the lock, we switch threads. frob2 comes in on thread 2, we take the lock on frob1 from the queue -- it's still there --, we switch threads.  Thread 1 removes the item from the queue.  Now thread 3 passes in frob3, we check the queue, it is empty because thread 1 just emptied it, we put frob 3 in the queue and enter the lock, and once again we have frob2 and frob3 both in the lock at the same time.

Comment: @EricLippert what you said makes sense, however I wrote this code assuming the lock would work if I overrode the `.Equals` method to check strings rather than the object reference (so in my mind the `lock` would work even if I wasn't comparing the object from the queue at all). Since you explained this is not the case, now I realize this code has a flaw, it's useless.

Comment: Yes, locking on strings is almost always wrong. But make sure you understand my comments though.  *This code is broken regardless of whether you're locking on strings and regardless if there are no deadlocks.* The code does not implement the invariant you wish to maintain: that the lock synchronizes access on the basis of the *value* of an object associated with the query.

Comment: @EricLippert thanks for sharing your knowledge and thoughts. I really need to rethink my solution, I think allowing duplicates to be inserted and using a recurrent job to once in while inspect recent entries and remove duplicates may not be the best solution, but it's much better (and simpler) than trying to use locks. Also, it works even if I ever needed to scale out. I think I'm gonna use this "job" for now, but I'll look for better solutions.

Comment: @Alisson: That sounds like a wise choice. I am of the opinion that having multiple threads of control in the same process, partying on the same virtual memory space, was a bad idea and we should stop encouraging people to do it. If it *must* be done then I prefer to think of threads as lightweight processes, where a thread is only spun up when there is a CPU to dedicate to it, and where it is only used to perform high latency CPU gated work. In your example it seems likely that you have many threads that are IO gated, not CPU gated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let me first make sure I understand the proposal. The problem given is that we have some resource shared to multiple threads, call it `database`, and it admits two operations: `Read(Context)` and `Write(Context)`.  The proposal is to have lock granularity based on a property of the context.  That is:

```
void MyRead(Context c) 
{
  lock(c.P) { database.Read(c); }
}
void MyWrite(Context c)
{
  lock(c.P) { database.Write(c); }
}
```

So now if we have a call to MyRead where the context property has value X, and a call to MyWrite where the context property has value Y, and the two calls are racing on two different threads, they are *not* serialized.  However, if we have, say, two calls to MyWrite and a call to MyRead, and in all of them the context property has value Z, those calls *are* serialized.

Is this *possible*? Yes. That doesn't make it a good idea. As implemented above, this is a bad idea and you shouldn't do it.

It is instructive to learn why it is a bad idea.

First, this simply fails if the property is a value type, like an integer. You might think, well, my context is an ID number, that's an integer, and I want to serialize all accesses to the database using ID number 123, and serialize all accesses using ID number 345, but not serialize those accesses with respect to each other. **Locks only work on reference types**, and **boxing a value type always gives you a freshly allocated box**, so the lock would *never* be contested even if the ids were the same.  It would be completely broken.

Second, it fails badly if the property is a string. Locks are logically "compared" by *reference*, not by *value*.  With boxed integers, you always get different references. With strings, you *sometimes* get different references! (Because of *interning* being applied inconsistently.) You could be in a situation where you are locking on "ABC" and *sometimes* another lock on "ABC" waits, and sometimes it does not!

But the fundamental rule that is broken is: *you must never lock on an object unless that object has been specifically designed to be a lock object, and the same code which controls access to the locked resource controls access to the lock object*.

The problem here is not "local" to the lock but rather global. Suppose your property is a `Frob` where `Frob` is a reference type.  **You don't know if any other code in your process is also locking on that same `Frob`**, and therefore you don't know what lock ordering constraints are necessary to prevent deadlocks.  Whether a program deadlocks or not is a *global* property of a program.  Just like you can build a hollow house out of solid bricks, you can build a deadlocking program out of a collection of locks that are individually correct.  By ensuring that every lock is only taken out on a *private object that you control*, you ensure that no one else is ever locking on one of your objects, and therefore the analysis of whether your program contains a deadlock becomes simpler.

Note that I said "simpler" and not "simple".  It reduces it to *almost impossible to get correct*, from *literally impossible to get correct*.

So if you were hell bent on doing this, what would be the right way to do it?

The right way would be to implement a new service: a *lock object provider*.  `LockProvider<T>` needs to be able to *hash* and *compare for equality* two `T`s.  The service it provides is: you tell it that you want a lock object for a particular value of `T`, and it gives you back the canonical lock object for that `T`. When you're done, you say you're done.  The provider keeps a reference count of how many times it has handed out a lock object and how many times it got it back, and deletes it from its dictionary when the count goes to zero, so that we don't have a memory leak.

Obviously the lock provider needs to be threadsafe and needs to be extremely low contention, because *it is a mechanism designed to prevent contention*, so it had better not *cause* any!  If this is the road you intend to go down, **you need to get an expert on C# threading to design and implement this object**.  It is very easy to get this wrong.  As I have noted in comments to your post, you are attempting to use a concurrent queue as a sort of poor lock provider and it is a mass of race condition bugs.

This is some of the hardest code to get correct in all of .NET programming. I have been a .NET programmer for almost 20 years and *implemented parts of the compiler* and I do not consider myself competent to get this stuff right.  Seek the help of an actual expert.

Comment: First of all, allow me thank you for your detailed answer, I really appreciate it (actually it's an honor). When you say *Locks are compared by reference*, how exactly does lock behave? Does it internally calls `.Equals` on both objects? If that is the case, I believe overriding `.Equals` and comparing strings and/or integers would do the job, however I'm still not sure this is the best approach, as I acknowledged this solution would fail if I ever wanted to scale out.

Comment: @Alisson: This comment is too short to explain how lock objects are implemented in .NET, but the short version is: **every single object of reference type in .NET has a synchronization block reserved in its memory image**, and that synchronization block is used to store the information needed when a lock is taken out on that object.  So the underlying mechanism does not ever need to compare two locks for equality; it just looks in the sync block to see if there is anything there.  That's why locks are always tied to a *specific object instance*; the information is actually in the object.

Comment: @EricLippert - It's sobering to hear you say "I do not consider myself competent to get this stuff right". What a superb answer. I don't know why it hasn't got 20 up-votes already.

Comment: @Enigmativity: I consider modern threading to be a massive failure of design at all levels: chip design, OS design, and language design. When you write a multi-threaded program the question you must answer is "are there any places in my program where its correctness depends on a *particular* ordering of reads and writes being observed?" No, wait, it is worse; C# does not even guarantee that a *consistent* ordering is observed, so really you must determine if your programs correctness depends on *a consistent ordering of all reads and writes being observed*.  If yes, you might have a bug.

Comment: @EricLippert - That's why I much prefer to use libraries like the TPL or Rx.NET (with the latter being my preferred option) as the level of abstraction helps to get things right.

Comment: @EricLippert after reading once again your answer, I decided to try some code, and I posted it as a possible answer to my question (although I'm not using that solution because it's kind useless when scaling out). Would you mind giving me some feedback?

Answer (score 0):

Although I find Eric Lippert's answer fantastic and marked it as the correct one (and I won't change that), his thoughts made me think and I wanted to share an alternative solution I found to this problem (and I'd appreciate any feedbacks), even though I'm not going to use it as I ended up using Azure functions with my code (so this wouldn't make sense), and a cron job to detected and eliminate possible duplicates.

```
public class UserScopeLocker : IDisposable
{
    private static readonly object _obj = new object();

    private static ICollection<string> UserQueue = new HashSet<string>();

    private readonly string _userId;

    protected UserScopeLocker(string userId)
    {
        this._userId = userId;
    }

    public static UserScopeLocker Acquire(string userId)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            lock (_obj)
            {
                if (UserQueue.Contains(userId))
                {
                    continue;
                }
                UserQueue.Add(userId);
                return new UserScopeLocker(userId);
            }
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        lock (_obj)
        {
            UserQueue.Remove(this._userId);
        }
    }
}
```

...then you would use it like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult ProcessPushNotification(PushRequest push)
{
    using(var scope = UserScopeLocker.Acquire(push.UserId))
    {
        // process the push notification
        // two threads can't enter here for the same UserId
        // the second one will be blocked until the first disposes
    }
}
```

The idea is:

- `UserScopeLocker` has a protected constructor, ensuring you call `Acquire`.
- `_obj` is private static readonly, only the `UserScopeLocker` can lock this object.
- `_userId` is a private readonly field, ensuring even its own class can't change its value.
- `lock` is done when checking, adding and removing, so two threads can't compete on these actions.

Possible flaws I detected:

- Since `UserScopeLocker` relies on `IDisposable` to release some `UserId`, I can't guarantee the caller will properly use `using` statement (or manually dispose the scope object).
- I can't guarantee the scope won't be used in a recursive function (thus possibly causing a deadlock).
- I can't guarantee the code inside the `using` statement won't call another function which also tries to acquire a scope to the user (this would also cause a deadlock).

Comment: You asked for feedback on this idea in another comment. I appreciate that you're trying here and I don't mean to be harsh, but this is not a good solution to this problem for a great many reasons; too many to explain in a couple of comments.  A few short takes.  First, if you want code reviewed, there is a stack exchange site specifically for that; it would be a more appropriate place to post this.

Comment: Second: you are trying to build a new higher-level concurrency mechanism out of lower level parts.  **That is good**.  We want to raise the level of abstraction of concurrency primitives.  However... you're doing so without having a strong understanding of the lower-level primitives you're building them out of.  That's bad, and you're making elementary design mistakes as a result. For example, the pattern of lock-in-a-loop we *immediately* know is bad because it creates huge amounts of contention.

Comment: If you understood how monitors work then you'd be using them to build a signal mechanism that puts waiting threads to sleep rather than looping around and trying the lock again. You've basically re-invented busy-waiting, the least efficient lock mechanism known to humankind, but it's busy-waiting that *also* heavily contends a single lock, which is *precisely the problem that your solution attempts to avoid*.

Comment: My advice is: first, simply don't do this at all. Having multiple threads of control that access a shared resource is in my opinion a bad pattern that leads to nothing but pain. If you're bent upon a multi-threaded shared-memory solution then *study how the fundamental parts work* before you try to invent a new one. For example, you should be able to write a correct producer-consumer queue in your sleep, with a thorough understanding of the various states that threads pass through as they are made to wait, made ready, and so on.

Comment: Basically, what I'm saying is that if you don't know enough to build from scratch *existing* higher-level concurrency mechanisms out of more primitive parts, then you are unlikely to be successful at building a *novel* concurrency mechanism successfully. **This is hard**.  As I said before, I do not consider myself competent to do this work, because I haven't spent decades studying how these mechanisms work. I've spent long enough studying them to know that I don't understand them nearly well enough to depart from standard patterns.

Comment: (And yes, your self-critique is spot on. In particular, abusing `using` to build a synchronization mechanism is a worst practice. One expects `using` to *politely release an unmanaged resource as early as possible*. One does not expect `using` to *introduce a new kind of synchronization mechanism*.  Make the code read like its meaning!)